# How to create a deployment package for a Sharepoint 2010 webpart in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: development, visual-studio

This might be a dumb question, but i really tried to google and didnt find any good answer.

I was developing some webparts for SharePoint 2007 in Visual Studio 2008, and when i would build my project, it would create a setup.bat file and a solution dir, the bat file would accept server address as a parameter and would install everything into the server, if ran from the computer which hosts the sharepoint server. Solution directory contained a folder per webpart with a feature.xml file and another folder inside each folder with .webpart and .xml file, and also the solution directory would have the dll assembly with the code.

Now, i am tasked to change something in those, and unfortunately i lost the project (the virtual PC hosting it was "lost" and no backup was done of it). I reverse engeneered everything from my dll. We have moved to SP2010 and VS2010 by now.

So, I created a new Sharepoint 2010 project in VS 2010 and re-created the webparts i had before. But now when i build the project, it only creates the assembly dll and nothing else.

I also have a "deploy" feature that doesnt work, it fails at "activation" step with "unauthorised operation" error. But that doesnt matter, since i need to install the assempbly to a PC hosting sharepoint, and its located in another domain, so i need to get my webparts packed in the way they were packed when i worked in Visual Studio 2008 - some batch file or something that i can run on target PC to install/update the webparts.

And i have a "package" option that makes some 1KB .package file that doesnt seem to contain anything useful at all.

I tried looking inside project properties but i cannot find anything relevant. There are so few options and neither seems to be related. I am really confused now - did they remove the option to create a stand-alone package?

I hope someone can enlighten me on this.

Thanks!

Edit: Sorry i dont understand how to reply to the message (so it shows as a string of text, not an answer) in this site (reply link is missing) so i'll add to my post.

Yes it does make a .wsp file, but this file isnt recognised by windows (server with sharepoint 2010 up and running) so i didnt notice it. I'll read more on what this file is and how to install it.

Comment: Is there no *.wsp* file created? That's the package you need.

Comment: You said a .package file is created - are you sure you chose to create a SharePoint 2010 Project and not some other kind? Create a fresh Empty SharePoint 2010 project and package that one for testing purposes. You should get a **wsp** file.

Comment: Check out if you are using the Visual Studio Tools for SharePoint 2010 correctly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/SP2010DevTrainingCourse_VisualStudio2010ToolsForSharePoint2010Intro and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620619

Answer (score 3):

Did you use the solution structure correctly. You should also register Feature files correctly as shown in this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/01/28/creating-a-sharepoint-visual-web-part-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Before you start 2010 development I would recommend that you install

1) SharePoint SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12323

2) SharePoint Community Kit: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee876627-962c-4c35-a4a6-a4d89bfb61dc

Then create an empty SharePoint project, and add new item - Web Part. This will create all the project artifacts you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Chapter 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798298.aspx) of [Inside SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742318.aspx). It talks about how to move from the "12 Hive" project structure we used with Visual Studio 2008 to the project structure used in Visual Studio 2010. It also discusses the Visual Studio 2010 automated packaging and deployment tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go to Package folder in your project and double click on Package.package, and add missing items into the package and redeploy it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting this, excuse me...

The package folder is the BIN/DEBUG or BIN/RELEASE folder - the WSP is created there. This is created anytime you deploy a web part to a SharePoint site, but you can also simply right-click on the project name (not solution) and select Package - that will build it as well (remember: based on your configuration settings - Debug or Release).

The WSP file is the standard deployment - you can use either stsadm -o addsolution or PowerShell Add-SPSolution.

David Sterling
davidmsterling.blogspot.com
www.sterling-consulting.com
www.sharepoint-blog.com